# Measuring physical quantities and spatial displacement

Tags: measurements

Do all measuring tools work by interacting with the physical property of interest and then changing spatially?  Can we only quantify physical properties this way?

A clock interacts with time and changes spatially.

A mercury thermometer maps the displacement of volume to a unit of temperature.

Or a weight scale on earth, it maps a springs displacement to a unit of mass. A balance is similar.

A bed of clay can be used to measure the energy of falling objects by measuring the volume of the impression.

A meter stick needs to be moved along an object and counted in order to quantify its length.

Maybe this is all completely apparent to most, but I haven't found much discussion about it.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Litmus paper measures acidity by changing colour. Do you count this as a "spatial" change ?

Comment: I believe litmus paper is a qualitative measurement.

Comment: Universal indicator also measures pH by changing colour and is able to give you numerical measurement.

Comment: Yes, I see how that can be quantitative.   However,  the paper interacts with the solution by displacing its electrons.  The measuring device changes spatially.

Answer (score 1):

No, in precision measurements things are usually meant to be returned to zero by some method. For example, when measuring a resistor using what is now called the Wheatstone's bridge and a galvanometer, the adjustments are made to make the galvanometer measure zero current, thus returning to where it started.

Comment: I think no displacement of the measuring device would quantify zero.  In that particular example how did you measure the values of the other resistors?

Comment: Usually the other resistors are either chosen beforehand and measured beforehand, with only just one resistor altered to fit the unknown. The alteration can be done electrically if you really must have no displacement.